# What is the difference between using Safe Args for screen transitions and not using them?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

[Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#safeargs)

I was referencing the JetPack Navigation Component related documentation to create a bottom navigation for screen transitions.

But in that link it says:

> - The recommended way to navigate between destinations is to use the Safe Args Gradle plugin.
> - Safe Args is recommended both for navigating as well as passing data between destinations.

After seeing this, I have a few questions.

Is there a performance difference between just using the `navaigation component` and using `safe args`?

Of course, `safe args` even has the ability to pass data between screens. But apart from this, is there any difference only in terms of screen transitions (navigation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safe Args just generates code that you can write yourself, following the [guide to navigating by ID](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#id) and [manually passing a `Bundle` of arguments](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#bundle) - it has no effect on the performance of your app at runtime or how screen transitions work.

Comment: So, does that mean there is no difference in screen transition performance between just using a normal `navigation component` and using `safe args`? 
However, does it mean that it is more convenient to use `safe args` if you need to pass data between screens?

Comment: The 'safe' part of Safe Args is the important part - it will only show you actions that are valid from a particular screen. Since the generated code is based on your navigation graph, you'll get a compile time error if you change your graph, but not your code that calls `navigate()`. If you don't use Safe Args, you'll have to make extra sure that those manually stay in sync to ensure that your call to `navigate()` doesn't throw an exception at runtime. The arguments are just a nice extra on top of that.

Comment: So overall... Are you saying that navigation using `safe args` is better than general `Navigation Component` (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#Set-up)?

Comment: Safe Args is part of the Navigation Component and mentioned specifically on that Getting Started page. They aren't separate things.

Comment: I barely understood...

I think it would be better to just use safe args.

Comment: That's why the docs you quoted in your question very specifically say "The recommended way to navigate between destinations is to use the Safe Args Gradle plugin."

Comment: When I look at the sample code, I can't see the example using `safe args` well, so I just asked an example using the navigation component. Thank you.

Comment: The only example of calling `navigate` on the Getting Started page you linked to uses Safe Args. What sample code are you looking at?

Comment: General code examples posted by other people other than developer documentation.. Found on Google..(This is the screen switching method I referenced.. not safe args. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate)

Those people did not use `safe args` and switched screens with only the `Navigation Component`, so I was wondering why they didn't use `safe args`, contrary to the recommendations of the developer documentation.
But there doesn't seem to be any other special reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to respond to a comment on an answer, but I found some of the comments to the only answer so far a bit misleading/incomplete.

For example, this line:

"... The 'safe' part of Safe Args is the important part - it will only show you actions that are valid from a particular screen... The arguments are just a nice extra on top of that..."

---

Another important aspect of safe args in general/what "safe" in "safe args" means (in my understanding) wasn't mentioned, which is that it gives you type safety.

quote: "Safe Args is strongly recommended for navigating and passing data, because it ensures type-safety."
link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Basically, without safe args, there's no way for the receiver to force the sender to send all the data required. Also, when unwrapping the data on the receiver's end, type safety isn't guaranteed... Safe args solves these problems.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/19327407-using-safe-args-with-the-android-navigation-component